# Pimcore plugin for netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, module, pimcore

I have a problem, I'm developing Pimcore plugin for Netbeans IDE, I have already developed code assistance for view methods but, I'm not able to add it to code assistance in php files, in html files it works well. I'm using this tutorial https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html, where is MimeRegistration annotation so I need a MimeType of PHP file or any other way how to do it. Do you have any idea how to proceed it?

Answer (score 0):

Since Pimcore is based mainly on Zend Framework, you should try if there is any integration for that with Netbeans.